# How can I resolve this improper integral?

Tags: numerical-methods, improper-integrals, matlab

I would like to resolve this [integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muguX.png) numerically . However, I'm not sure about the best way to do it because it is an improper integral:

$$ \Phi(\rho)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\phi_1(s)sJ_0(s\rho)\mathrm{d}s$$
$$ \phi_1(s)=\frac{1}{D_1\alpha_1}\left[\sinh(\alpha_1z_0)\cdot\frac{D_1\alpha_1\cosh(\alpha_1l)+D_2\alpha_2\sinh(\alpha_1l)}{D_1\alpha_1\cosh(\alpha_1(l+z_b))+D_2\alpha_2\sinh(\alpha_1(l+z_b))}-\sinh(\alpha_1z_0)\right], $$
$$ \alpha_i=\sqrt{\frac{D_is^2+\mu a}{D_i}}. $$

I have studied the function $\phi_1$.

[image]

The function $\phi_1$ converges when s approaches infinity.

I have already simplified $\phi_1$'s expression with Taylor's formula.
$$\phi_1(s) = \frac{1}{2 D_1 \alpha_1 }\cdot [(e^{\alpha_1 (z_b+z_0)}-e^{-\alpha_1 (z_b+z_0)})\times \frac{(1+k)e^{\alpha_1 l} +(1-k)e^{-\alpha_1 l}}{(1+k)e^{\alpha_1 (l+z_b)} +(1-k)e^{-\alpha_1 (l+z_b)}}]$$

with $k = \frac{\alpha_2 D_2}{\alpha_1 D_1}$
Then,
$$\phi_1 (s)= \frac{1}{2 D_1 \alpha_1} \cdot [(1+\alpha_1(z_b+z_0) - 1 + \alpha_1(z_b+z_0))\times \frac{(1+\alpha_1l)(1+k)+(1-\alpha_1l)(1-k)}{(1+\alpha_1(l+z_b))(1+k)+(1-\alpha_1(l+z_b))(1-k)}]$$
$$\lim_{\alpha_1\to 0} \frac{z_b + z_0}{D_1}$$

I have also tried the following variable substitution:
$$ u=s\rho, $$
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^x\phi_1 \left(\frac{u}{\rho}\right)\frac{u}{\rho}J_0(u)\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\rho}. $$

I would appreciate some advice how to proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: Please try to type your equations out-see the mathjax tutorial for more if unfamiliar with it-http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: There seems to be a typo. You start of with two different definitions of $\phi_1$ and then start talking about a $\phi$ that wasn't introduced -- so presumably one of those $\phi_1$ was meant to be $\phi$?

Comment: What is $x$? Why is this integral improper?

Comment: There's still a typo. Now you've introduced a function $\Phi$ but then start talking about a function $\phi$ that hasn't been introduced.

Comment: Matlab's [`integral` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html?searchHighlight=improper) (formerly `quad`) can deal with improper integrals.

Comment: Thank you, `integral`works !